# Is there a way to read in or connect to a compact SQL database file (.sdf) in R?

Tags: r, database

I have a measurement device that stores data in a compact SQL database (.sdf) file: [Compact SQL File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact). Looking for a method to load this data into R. Attempted this:

```
library(RSQLite)
db <- "database.sdf"
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), db)
```

Doesn't throw an error but also doesn't report back any tables.

Comment: Does `odbc::dbListTables()`, with the appropriate connection and schema arguments, show you the available tables? The [Introduction to `dbplyr` vignette](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dbplyr.html) provides basic code for getting data from databases using tidyverse functions, and uses a SQLite backend for the examples.

Comment: The [Databases using R](https://db.rstudio.com/) area of RStudio might also be helpful.